# javascript for...in loops please explain

Tags: javascript, loops, for-in-loop

My first question on here and need help understanding the for in loop in JavaScript.

When I run the following code I get "undefined" from the alert function:

```
var o = {
  a: "property 1", 
  b: "property 2", 
  c: "property 3", 
  d: "property 4"
}

for (p in o) {
  alert(o.p); 
}
```

but if I were to change `.` to `[ ]` (ie. `alert(o[p])`) the alert would return the property value as expected.

Why can't  I use `.` to access the object property?

Comment: Because it has no way of knowing that you want to use the variable `p` instead of a property named `p`. Therfore the `.` operator is specifically for names of property identifiers *(whether or not they exist)*, whereas `[]` is for using the result of any expression as the property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a closer look at this for in loop:

```
var obj = {
  a: "property 1", 
  b: "property 2", 
  c: "property 3", 
  d: "property 4"
}
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (typeof(prop) == 'string') {
        console.log('This is a string!');
    }
}
```

You will notice that the what the for in loop is giving you is the name of the property.
That's why it would be ok to use `obj[prop]` because the property would be a string and that is a legal way to access a property of an object.

When you try and execute `obj.prop` it gives you undefined because property is a string that represents the name of a property, it's not the actual property.

Comment: Awesome, I understand now, prop is a string and thus would be like saying obj."prop" and that is not legal. obj["prop"] is legal.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you have this object:

```
var o = {
  a: "property 1", 
  b: "property 2", 
  c: "property 3", 
  d: "property 4",
  p: "property 5"
}
```

and run the following:

```
for (p in o) {
  console.log(o.p);
}
```

the result will be:

```
property 5
property 5
property 5
property 5
property 5
```

Because `o.p` means that you want to get the value of a property named `p`.

Similarly in your example, the property `p` is not defined in your object.

If you want to get the value of a property via a **string**, you must use `[]` notation.

Answer (score 2):

```
o[p]
```

is p-th element in array o.

```
o.p
```

is property p of array o, which is correctly reported as undefined, as it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

o.p means the property "p" of `o`.

o["p"] means the same thing.

o[x] means some property (whose value is defined by variable `x`) of `o`.

o[p] the same.